# Magento: Can not change value of Mage::getSingleton(’core/session’)?

Tags: php, magento, mage

I have an extension

in the Controller php file I have line below

```
public function accountverificationAction() {
        $customerEmail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $mobile_num = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile_number');
        $mobile_code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile_code');        
        $smsModel = Mage::getModel('ardindata/ardindata');

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('mobile');

        if($mobile_num) {
            $sms_response = $smsModel->sendSms($mobile_num,$customerEmail);
            if(is_numeric($sms_response)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('code');
            } else {
                if(empty($sms_response)) {
                    $message = $this->__('Error: Please enter a valid mobile number');
                } else {
                    $message = $this->__('Error: '.$sms_response);
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
            }
        }

    if($mobile_code) {
        $verificationCompleted = $smsModel->customerVerification($customerEmail,$mobile_code);
        if($verificationCompleted != '1') {
            $message = $this->__('Verification Failed!');
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
        }
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

So, I set value "**mobile**" first to **Mage::getSingleton('core/session')** … I want to change it to "**code**" after **if(is_numeric($sms_response))** but it don’t change and echo only "**mobile**" !

I don’t know why, can anyone help me to solve it ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning new value to core/session variable, you need to unset old assigned value.

Complete code of function after correction:

```
public function accountverificationAction() {
    $customerEmail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    $mobile_num = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile_number');
    $mobile_code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile_code');        
    $smsModel = Mage::getModel('ardindata/ardindata');

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('mobile');

    if($mobile_num) {
        $sms_response = $smsModel->sendSms($mobile_num,$customerEmail);
        if($sms_response) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsVerificationphase();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('code');
        } else {
            if(empty($sms_response)) {
                $message = $this->__('Error: Please enter a valid mobile number');
            } else {
                $message = $this->__('Error: '.$sms_response);
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did test before, but not work! --- it seems that value can not go outside of the if !!

Comment: core/session variable is global not restricted to scope, try to print `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVerificationphase();` before unset and set of new value into session variable.

Comment: I set echo `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVerificationphase();` in the template file and set echo `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVerificationphase();` after `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('code');` in the controller file... but I don't know why in the template file "code" can not return and all time is "mobile" !-- in the template : `$verification_failure = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVerificationphase();
 echo $verification_failure;
 if(empty($verification_failure) || ($verification_failure == 'mobile')):`

Comment: It means, `if(is_numeric($sms_response))` is not true and it doesn't unset/update session variable. OR you can update in condition with `if($sms_response)` line of code. then add unset/set session variable.

Comment: not work again, `if(is_numeric($sms_response))` is true because return "code" when sending sms but don't show in template file, when I echo `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVerificationphase();` after `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVerificationphase('code');` in the controller file then "code" appear under the "mobile" in the template file and don't pass to `else`! I don't know how can I explain more

Comment: I have updated complete function code, just replace your code with this code and try again after clearing all cache from admin.

Comment: as I told you before this method don't work, it is very simple but not working and it wasted 3 days of my life!!

Comment: Also, I have wasted few hours. Now, enable your log from system->configuration->developer->log settings and process account verification functionality and see if there is any thing help full in log. This is last option or you have to debug line by line process

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to solve this problem but nothing again, system.log didn't created and not log is available!

Comment: If issue has not been solved.. then No Thanks :( ..... Other way you can try. Set new core/session variable under if condition and in template check if this new core/session variable is set or not. If set then use new variable value otherwise old one. For now, at-least you can move to other part and come again when get some extra/free time.

Comment: This is my only problem, all of the part is ok, I have completed the first post with full code, please see it again, is this possible problem is from `$this->loadLayout();` and `$this->renderLayout();` ?